# Sponsored tags are too tall

Tags: bug, design, sponsored-tags

Sponsored tags are **4 whole pixels** taller (28px) than their unsponsored brethren (a mere 24px). Take a look:

[image]

This is a horrible injustice. Please, *oh please*, fix this.

Comment: Look at that horribly pixelated icon, too. Tsk.

Comment: @J.Steen SVGifying would be a [tag:feature-request]

Comment: @Mooseman Which is why I commented rather than go on an oft-derided rant about the lack of hidpi-support. And with the other implemented support for hidpi with SVG-logo and whatnot, I see that as a bug now. ;)